# Using Sibling Combinator to create tabs for dynamic content

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

I'm basing my tab implementation on the following:

https://codepen.io/oknoblich/pen/tfjFl

Within this pen, we have the following structure:

```
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Codepen</label>

  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Dribbble</label>

  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">Dropbox</label>

  <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab4">Drupal</label>

  <section id="content1">
    content1
  </section>

  <section id="content2">
    content2
  </section>

  <section id="content3">
   content3
  </section>

  <section id="content4">
    content4
  </section>
```

With tabbing made possible by sibling selectors:

```
section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3,
#tab4:checked ~ #content4 {
  display: block;
}
```

However I have several "panes" that each require their own tabs, so the `name` and `id` attributes are dynamic.

Within a `foreach` loop that renders the html, I have this:

```
        <div class="tabs-container">

            <input data-bind="attr:{id: 'tab1-' + factorPaneId, name: 'tabs1-' + factorPaneId}" type="radio" checked>
            <label data-bind="attr:{for: 'tab1-' + factorPaneId">Description</label>

            <input data-bind="attr:{id: 'tab2-' + factorPaneId, name: 'tabs2-' + factorPaneId}" type="radio" checked>
            <label data-bind="attr:{for: 'tab2-' + factorPaneId">Description</label>

            <section data-bind="attr:{id: 'content1-' + factorPaneId">
                <p data-bind="text: factor.factorDescription"></p>
            </section>

            <section data-bind="attr:{id: 'content2-' + factorPaneId">
                <p data-bind="text: factor.factorDescription"></p>
            </section>
        </div>
```

But I'm not sure how to modify the CSS to support this need for dynamic `id`s.  Specifically this bit:

```
#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3,
#tab4:checked ~ #content4 {
  display: block;
}
```

I need some way to say:

```
#tab1-*:checked ~ #content1-*{
  display: block;
}
```

Where the `*`s are equal.  Is there a CSS/HTML-only solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try using the CSS attribute starts with selector (`^=`) for the `id`.

Like this:

```
[id^="tab1"]:checked ~ [id^="content1"],
[id^="tab2"]:checked ~ [id^="content2"],
[id^="tab3"]:checked ~ [id^="content3"],
[id^="tab4"]:checked ~ [id^="content4"] {
  display: block;
}
```

Here is an updated [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aGBjpe).

Answer (score 0):

You can also target them based in the order of ocurrence

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  font: 14px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #555;
  background: #eee;
}

h1 {
  padding: 50px 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

main {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

label:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

label[for*='1']:before { content: '\f1cb'; }
label[for*='2']:before { content: '\f17d'; }
label[for*='3']:before { content: '\f16b'; }
label[for*='4']:before { content: '\f1a9'; }

label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked + label {
  color: #555;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 2px solid orange;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ section:nth-of-type(1),
input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ section:nth-of-type(2),
input:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ section:nth-of-type(3),
input:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ section:nth-of-type(4) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1>Responsive CSS Tabs</h1>

<main>
  
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Codepen</label>
    
  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Dribbble</label>
    
  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">Dropbox</label>
    
  <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab4">Drupal</label>
    
  <section id="content1">
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet beef venison beef ribs kielbasa. Sausage pig leberkas, t-bone sirloin shoulder bresaola. Frankfurter rump porchetta ham. Pork belly prosciutto brisket meatloaf short ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
      Brisket meatball turkey short loin boudin leberkas meatloaf chuck andouille pork loin pastrami spare ribs pancetta rump. Frankfurter corned beef beef tenderloin short loin meatloaf swine ground round venison.
    </p>
  </section>
    
  <section id="content2">
    <p>
      2Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet landjaeger sausage brisket, jerky drumstick fatback boudin ball tip turducken. Pork belly meatball t-bone bresaola tail filet mignon kevin turkey ribeye shank flank doner cow kielbasa shankle. Pig swine chicken hamburger, tenderloin turkey rump ball tip sirloin frankfurter meatloaf boudin brisket ham hock. Hamburger venison brisket tri-tip andouille pork belly ball tip short ribs biltong meatball chuck. Pork chop ribeye tail short ribs, beef hamburger meatball kielbasa rump corned beef porchetta landjaeger flank. Doner rump frankfurter meatball meatloaf, cow kevin pork pork loin venison fatback spare ribs salami beef ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
      Jerky jowl pork chop tongue, kielbasa shank venison. Capicola shank pig ribeye leberkas filet mignon brisket beef kevin tenderloin porchetta. Capicola fatback venison shank kielbasa, drumstick ribeye landjaeger beef kevin tail meatball pastrami prosciutto pancetta. Tail kevin spare ribs ground round ham ham hock brisket shoulder. Corned beef tri-tip leberkas flank sausage ham hock filet mignon beef ribs pancetta turkey.
    </p>
  </section>
    
  <section id="content3">
    <p>
      3Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet beef venison beef ribs kielbasa. Sausage pig leberkas, t-bone sirloin shoulder bresaola. Frankfurter rump porchetta ham. Pork belly prosciutto brisket meatloaf short ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
      Brisket meatball turkey short loin boudin leberkas meatloaf chuck andouille pork loin pastrami spare ribs pancetta rump. Frankfurter corned beef beef tenderloin short loin meatloaf swine ground round venison.
    </p>
  </section>
    
  <section id="content4">
    <p>
      4Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet landjaeger sausage brisket, jerky drumstick fatback boudin ball tip turducken. Pork belly meatball t-bone bresaola tail filet mignon kevin turkey ribeye shank flank doner cow kielbasa shankle. Pig swine chicken hamburger, tenderloin turkey rump ball tip sirloin frankfurter meatloaf boudin brisket ham hock. Hamburger venison brisket tri-tip andouille pork belly ball tip short ribs biltong meatball chuck. Pork chop ribeye tail short ribs, beef hamburger meatball kielbasa rump corned beef porchetta landjaeger flank. Doner rump frankfurter meatball meatloaf, cow kevin pork pork loin venison fatback spare ribs salami beef ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
      Jerky jowl pork chop tongue, kielbasa shank venison. Capicola shank pig ribeye leberkas filet mignon brisket beef kevin tenderloin porchetta. Capicola fatback venison shank kielbasa, drumstick ribeye landjaeger beef kevin tail meatball pastrami prosciutto pancetta. Tail kevin spare ribs ground round ham ham hock brisket shoulder. Corned beef tri-tip leberkas flank sausage ham hock filet mignon beef ribs pancetta turkey.
    </p>
  </section>
    
</main>
```